# about OOP and inherited classes

Tags: java, oop

im new here...
i have a little question regarding OOP rules.
let's say we have 3 classes:Bird,Cat & dog.
for both dog and cat have a fourlegs() method, and all of them have an eat() mathod.
what is the best way to accomplish this task:
*create Animal class with eat(), create Pet class with fourlegs() which will inherit from Animal class.
after then,cat &dog classes inherit from Pet while bird only inherit from Animal.
*since that there are differenet mathods for several classes object-oriented is not relevant here.
thank you very much!

Comment: Where is the code you are talking about

Comment: "since that there are differenet mathods for several classes object-oriented is not relevant here" - what makes you say/write that?

Comment: Your task is also quite plainly put, i.e. you have to create a class hierarchy that is somewhat well described. Where's the problem?

Comment: Why shouldn't bird inherit from Pet? Are they not acceptable as pets?

Comment: You probably need an `Animal` class, which is inherited by `Mammal` and `Bird`, which are inherited by their respective creatures.

Comment: You might want to add your real life situation as an example, since it seems on the surface that there isnt much problem with your idea.

Comment: all the 3 can eat in common, but only cat and dog have also fourlegs() method.

Comment: I still can't figure out what's the question/problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost answer your own question. Create a class-hierarchy with the "Animal"-interface as the top-node.

[I made an example of the hierarchy here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww7J4.png)

Also, inheritance and polymorphi is some of the essentials of OOP, so I don't get your last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a interface / abstract class `Animal`. `Bird`, `Cat` and `Dog` inherit from Animal.
Since the number of legs is something that cannot be categorized by making them depend on `Mammal`, `Pet` or something else, I would define an interface `FourLegged`. This would also enable you to not bind `fly()` to bird... there are birds that can't fly and insects that can fly:

```
public abstract class Animal {}

public interface FourLegged {}

public interface Flyer {}

public class Dog extends Animal implements FourLegged {}

public class Bird extends Animal implements Flyer {}
```

It depends on your needs whether `Animal` is an interface or an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following sample code:

1. Declare class Animal

   ```
   class Animal(){

       void eat(){
           ... do something ...
       }

   }
   ```
2. Declare class Pet

   ```
    class Pet() extends Animal{
         /* This class has inherited eat() method as declared in class Animal. 
             If you want to change it, you must use @Override. */

         void fourlegs(){
             ... do something ...
         }
    }
   ```
3. Declare classes Dog and Cat

   ```
    class Dog extends Pet{
        /* This class has inherited both eat() and fourlegs() from class Pet. */
        ...
    }
   ```

and the same for class Cat.

4. Declare class Bird

   ```
    class Bird extends Animal{
          /* This class has inherited eat() method as declared in class Animal.    
          ...
    }
   ```

OOP programming is certainly related to this exercise, as you need to use inheritance (which is one of OOP's characteristics) in order to accomplish it.